# SessionNotFoundException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()? (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to write some selenium automated UI tests using Cucumber/Java.  If I have only one test in my feature file, everything works fine.  But if I add a second test, I get this error on `driver.get()`:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '2.51.0', revision: '1af067dbcaedd7d2ab9af5151fc471d363d97193', time: '2016-02-05 11:20:57'
```

Basically, I am initializing the webdriver variable on the InitializeWebdriver class in one package, and then referencing it in the other (step definition) classes.  I did have the step definition listed below as a part of the InitializeWebdriver class, and it was working just fine (until moved on to a different step in a different class.  So I moved that step to a CommonSteps.java file to see if it would then fail, and it did.  So now I'm just stuck.  I was thinking of doing an `if (driver.equals(null))` in the `@Before` and doing a different action if had already been initialized, but I don't know what that other action would be.

Here is my code:

tests.feature

```
Feature:  Two tests

Background:
    Given I navigate to "http://www.google.com"

Scenario: Test one
    When something happens

Scenario: Test two
    When something else happens
```

InitializeWebDriver.java

```
public class InitializeWebDriver {

    public static WebDriver driver = null;

    @Before
    public void beforeScenario() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @After
    public void afterScenario() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

CommonSteps.java

```
import myPackage.InitializeWebDriver;

public class CommonSteps {

    static WebDriver driver = InitializeWebDriver.driver;

    @Given("^I navigate to \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_navigate_to(String url) {
        driver.get(value);
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I had this error when I tried to take a screenshot after using the method `driver.quit()`. Just had to switch lines.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I don't think `driver` is `null`, that would cause a `NullPointerException` and it would have no way of knowing to convert it to a `SessionNotFoundException`. So it looks like `driver` has been created and then ended, i.e. `.quit()` has been called too soon, as suggested in the error message.

Here's what I think is happening:

1. It starts the first test and calls the `@Before`. This causes `InitializeWebDriver.driver` to be set as the new `WebDriver`.
2. Only after that does it load the class `CommonSteps`, so `CommonSteps.driver` is set to the `WebDriver` that was just created.
3. The test runs successfully, and `.quit()` is called on the `WebDriver`, in the `@After` method.
4. Then it starts the second test. A new `WebDriver` is created in the `@Before` method. `InitializeWebDriver.driver` is updated; however, `CommonSteps.driver` is not updated, because the `driver = InitializeWebDriver.driver;` only happens when `CommonSteps` is first loaded.
5. Therefore, when it gets to `driver.get(value)`, `driver` is the original `WebDriver`, which has already been `.quit()`.

This is assuming you're running the tests in series. If they're in parallel then it will be a bit different.

Basically the problem is that you're using static attributes for `WebDriver`, which shouldn't be shared between different test runs. It's a while since I've done this stuff, and I don't remember how you store variables scoped to a test run. (In any case I wouldn't be able to answer with certainty, since you haven't said which test framework you're using: JUnit, or something else?) So you'll have to fix it yourself, or ask how to get test-scoped variables in whatever framework you're using.

That's if you want to do it properly. If you just want a cheap fix, and if you're not planning to run tests in parallel, I suspect that you can fix it by changing `driver.get(value);` to `InitializeWebDriver.driver.get(value);`. In fact, I suggest you try changing that anyway, just to make sure I'm right about this.

Comment: Yup, changing `driver` to `InitializeWebDriver.driver` in CommonSteps.java fixed it.  As you said, though, not a great solution.  I'm using Junit for my assertions, but I'm using Cucumber for the hooks (`cucumber.api.java.Before`/`After`). I have no idea how to set this up, so really any help at all would be super helpful.

Comment: You could try changing the tags for this question. Would something junit-related help? Certainly you don't need the selenium-webdriver and selenium-chromedriver tags, since we've agreed it's a test variable scoping issue.