# FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setup org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?

Tags: java, variables, selenium-chromedriver, testng-eclipse

I found few similar issues here(
[SessionNotFoundException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()? (Selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352248/sessionnotfoundexception-session-id-is-null-using-webdriver-after-calling-quit/48654830?noredirect=1#comment84307834_48654830)

[org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42823201/org-openqa-selenium-nosuchsessionexception-session-id-is-null-using-webdriver)
)
but none of them did not help me to solve my issue.
Any help or advice will be appreciated.

In my case I am using TestNG.
I have created Main Class

```
package base;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class MainClass {

      public WebDriver driver;
      public Properties CONFIG;
      public Properties XPATH;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void initialization() throws IOException {   
        String chromeDriverLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/java/driverlocation/chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverLocation);

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        System.out.println("Web Driver initilization has started...");
        System.out.println("In the before suite...");

        CONFIG = new Properties();
        String configLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/java/base/Config.properties";
        FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream(configLocation);
        CONFIG.load(ip);

        XPATH = new Properties();
        String xpathLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/java/base/xpath.properties";
        FileInputStream xpathIp = new FileInputStream(xpathLocation);
        XPATH.load(xpathIp);
    }
     @AfterSuite
        public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("Web Driver is closing...");
        System.out.println("it is epic...");
        driver.quit();
}
}
```

And I have class with test which extends Main.Class

```
package Test.TileSearch;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import base.MainClass;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;


public class Tile1City1 extends MainClass  {


     @BeforeMethod 
       public void setup() throws Exception {
          driver.get(CONFIG.getProperty("urlcentura"));
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
      }

      @AfterMethod 
      public void tearDown() {
          driver.quit();
      }


       @Test
      public void main1() throws Exception  
            driver.findElement(By.xpath().click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath().click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath().click();

            if(!driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText("Tile")).isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println("Tile is available there");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Tile is not available there");
                }
      }

      @Test
      public void main1() throws Exception  
            driver.findElement(By.xpath().click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath().click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath().click();

            if(!driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText("Tile")).isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println("Tile is available there");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Tile is not available there");
                }
      }
    }
```

And here is error in console

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.13.1
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f) on port 11302
Only local connections are allowed.
Feb 06, 2018 8:13:19 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Web Driver initilization has started...
In the before suite...
Abaco is available there
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setup
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'
System info: host: 'EARL', ip: '192.168.1.85', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:325)
    at Test.CenturaSearch.AbacoMontreal.setup(AbacoMontreal.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:451)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:516)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:707)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:979)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1028)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:996)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod tearDown
PASSED: main
SKIPPED: main1
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'
System info: host: 'EARL', ip: '192.168.1.85', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:325)
    at Test.CenturaSearch.AbacoMontreal.setup(AbacoMontreal.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:451)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:516)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:707)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:979)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1028)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:996)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

Only one test is running, other always skips. 
Basically the problem is that I am using static attributes for WebDriver, which shouldn't be shared between different test runs.
Anyone knows how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're quitting the driver in Tile1City1

```
 @AfterMethod 
  public void tearDown() {
      driver.quit();
  }
```

So you open the driver in a @BeforeSuite, then quit it after one test and never re-open it.  I may be misreading the code, but that appears to be what is happening.

If you want a new driver per test, you need to also open your driver each test in a @BeforeMethod.

If you want to re-use the same driver for each test, remove the code I quoted from Tile1City1

Comment: @Serg,  have you get it fix ? If not, I can help you for same.

Answer (score 0):

inside Driver

```
 `public static void closeDriver() {
    if (driver != null) {    driver.quit();     driver = null;    }
    }`
```

and use this one in @AfterMethod
`Driver.closeDriver();`